# express validator - custom password validator cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, express-validator

I have a simple validator that checks if "password" = "passwordconf"

exports.RegisterUser = [

```
check('username').isLength({ min: 1 , max: 10}).trim().withMessage("Length 1-10"),
check('password').isLength({ min: 6 , max: 10}).trim().withMessage("Length 6-10"),
check('passwordconf').isLength({ min: 6 , max: 10}).trim().withMessage("Length 6-10"),
check('passwordconf').custom((value , { req }) => {
    if (value !== req.body.password) {
        throw new Error('Password confirmation is incorrect');
    } 
}),
sanitizeBody('*').trim().escape(),

function ( req , res ) {
    //check for errors
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
      } else {

        var user = new User({
            username : req.body.username,
            password : req.body.password
        });

        var username = req.body.username;
        //check if user is in DB
        User.findOne({ 'username' : username})
            .exec(( err , docs) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.send('There was an error');
                    return err;
                } else if (!docs) {
                    //username does not exist
                    user.save((err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return next(err)
                        } else {
                            //saved it
                            res.send('saved a new user!')
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    res.send('Username exists!')
                }                      
        })}
```

}]

if i comment out this statement,

```
check('passwordconf').custom((value , { req }) => {
        if (value !== req.body.password) {
            throw new Error('Password confirmation is incorrect');
        } 
    })
```

the code works.I copied this statement from the official docs https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html
I gives me this error when saving a new user

```
{"errors":[{"location":"body","param":"passwordconf","value":"password1","msg":"Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"}]}
```

What is missing here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because there is no 3rd argument, to actually handle the request. (as in  their example `// Handle the request`). What line is triggering the error?

Comment: how would i put the 3rd argument?since i already have
`check('passwordconf').custom(...) , function ( req , res ) {}`.
Also the validator works and tells me if pword doesnt match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/593), and will be fixed in the next release (current one being v5.2.0).
Custom validators that return nothing fail with that error.

To work around this, you can simply return `true` from your validator:

```
check('passwordconf').custom((value , { req }) => {
    if (value !== req.body.password) {
        throw new Error('Password confirmation is incorrect');
    }

    return true;
})
```

Comment: Has been fixed since v5.3.0 release https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/593#issuecomment-407099024